# Why does `catch` catch the throw here?

Tags: c++, try-catch

I'm not really sure what's happening here. Its obvious why the inner catch catches `throw 2`, but why does the outher `catch(int x)` catch `throw`? I thought `catch(int x)` is supposed to catch integer values only. Is it possible that the second `throw` throws what was first cought (which is 2)?

```
try
{
    try
    {
        throw 2;
    }
    catch (int n)
    {
        std::cout << "Inner Catch " << n << std::endl;
        throw;
    }
}
catch (int x)
{
    std::cout << "Outer Catch " << x << std::endl;
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot `throw` nothing. `throw;` alone can be used in a catch-block to rethrow the currently handeled exception. From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/throw):

> Rethrows the currently handled exception. Abandons the execution of
> the current catch block and passes control to the next matching
> exception handler (but not to another catch clause after the same try
> block: its compound-statement is considered to have been 'exited'),
> reusing the existing exception object: no new objects are made. This
> form is only allowed when an exception is presently being handled (it
> calls std::terminate if used otherwise). The catch clause associated
> with a function-try-block must exit via rethrowing if used on a
> constructor.

---

> I thought catch(int x) is supposed to catch integer values only

Thats what it does.

> Is it possible that the second throw throws what was first cought (which is 2)?

Exactly that.

Comment: Thanks!! Just to clarify, using `throw` not in a catch-block will just result in termination of program without the ability to catch it? (not even with `std::Exception& e`)?

Comment: @user3265447 there is nothing special about `std::exception` other than it is commonly used when throwing exceptions. You can `throw` and `catch` without a single `std::exception` being involved. And yes, `throw;` outside of a catch block will call `std::terminate`